# How to get type hinting in phpStorm for an array to object function?

Tags: php, laravel, object, phpstorm, type-hinting

I need to have access to type hint like

> SapDefine::transactionCode()-> ...

For now am seeing hint for SapDefine:: ...

```
 class sapDefine extends ServiceProvider {     

  /**
  * @return object[]
  */
  public static function transactionCode() {
    return (object) [
        'RetailSales-DineIn'=>'ZR11',
        'RetailSales-TakeAway'=>'ZR12',
        'RetailReturn-DineIn'=>'ZR21',
        'RetailReturn-TakeAway'=>'ZR22',
        'DeliverySales-E-Coms'=>'ZD13',
        'DeliverySales-M-App'=>'ZD14',
        'DeliverySales-Phone'=>'ZD15',
        'DeliveryReturn-E-Coms'=>'ZD23',
        'DeliveryReturn-M-App'=>'ZD24',
        'DeliveryReturn-Phone'=>'ZD25',
        'EventSales-General'=>'ZE19',
        'EventReturn-General'=>'ZE29'
    ];
  }
}
```

ps. project is setup in laravel.

Comment: What would you like to be hinted ? The function returns an object literal with custom properties

Comment: I would like to see all sub array [name] or in this case sub object names.